# Bluetooth mouse problem

Tags: bluetooth

[SOLVED] So the problem was the distance between the receiver and the devices...I noticed when I put my mouse on my desk and not the keyboard pull-out drawer the errors stopped coming up and so I used a USB extension to move the receiver closer to the devices.

EDIT: Version Info and yes I use virtualization.  I use QEMU and KVM to run windows 10 in a VM with a VFIO passthrough.  I use libvirt to accomplish this with virt-manager and virt-viewer.  I have included version information for libvirt below.

Output from lsb_releases -a:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Output from uname -a:

```
Linux dreadnaught 5.3.0-40-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 31 20:24:34 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output from dpkg -l:

```
ii  libgovirt-common                           0.3.4-3.1                              all          GObject-based library to access oVirt REST API (common files)
ii  libgovirt2:amd64                           0.3.4-3.1                              amd64        GObject-based library to access oVirt REST API
ii  libsys-virt-perl                           5.0.0-1                                amd64        Perl module providing an extension for the libvirt library
ii  libvirglrenderer0:amd64                    0.7.0-2                                amd64        virtual GPU for KVM virtualization
ii  libvirt-clients                            5.4.0-0ubuntu5                         amd64        Programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt-daemon                             5.4.0-0ubuntu5                         amd64        Virtualization daemon
ii  libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd          5.4.0-0ubuntu5                         amd64        Virtualization daemon RBD storage driver
ii  libvirt-daemon-system                      5.4.0-0ubuntu5                         amd64        Libvirt daemon configuration files
ii  libvirt-glib-1.0-0:amd64                   2.0.0-1                                amd64        libvirt GLib and GObject mapping library
ii  libvirt0:amd64                             5.4.0-0ubuntu5                         amd64        library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii  openvpn                                    2.4.7-1ubuntu2                         amd64        virtual private network daemon
ii  ovmf                                       0~20190606.20d2e5a1-2ubuntu1           all          UEFI firmware for 64-bit x86 virtual machines
ii  python3-libvirt                            5.0.0-1                                amd64        libvirt Python 3 bindings
ii  qemu-kvm                                   1:4.0+dfsg-0ubuntu9.4                  amd64        QEMU Full virtualization on x86 hardware
ii  tigervnc-standalone-server                 1.9.0+dfsg-3                           amd64        Standalone virtual network computing server
ii  virt-manager                               1:2.2.1-0ubuntu2                       all          desktop application for managing virtual machines
ii  virt-viewer                                7.0-2                                  amd64        Displaying the graphical console of a virtual machine
ii  virtinst                                   1:2.2.1-0ubuntu2                       all          Programs to create and clone virtual machines
```

So I have a M705 and K350 wireless mouse and keyboard combo.  Every so often the mouse and keyboard go into a frenzy skipping all over the place with momentary disconnects and lag.  The issue seems to be related to this output from journalctl -f:

```
Mar 12 16:01:34 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:01:58 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:01:59 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:38 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:47 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:47 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:48 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:49 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:53 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:02:54 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:01 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:05 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:06 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:06 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:08 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:11 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:12 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:14 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:14 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:19 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:26 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:26 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:28 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
Mar 12 16:03:28 dreadnaught kernel: logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
```

Here is output from systemctl status bluetooth:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-03-12 15:32:18 EDT; 45min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 27763 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 1.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─27763 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught bluetoothd[27763]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught bluetoothd[27763]: Starting SDP server
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught bluetoothd[27763]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught bluetoothd[27763]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.5650 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Mar 12 15:32:18 dreadnaught bluetoothd[27763]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.5650 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
```

Output from dmesg relating to the event:

```
[Mar12 01:06] usb usb3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[Mar12 05:28] usb usb3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[Mar12 08:18] usb usb3-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[Mar12 08:32] usb 7-2: new low-speed USB device number 81 using ohci-pci
[Mar12 15:20] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:21] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:24] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:25] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:26] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:27] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:28] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:29] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:31] rfkill: input handler enabled
[Mar12 15:32] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:33] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:39] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:40] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:41] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:43] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:44] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:45] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:47] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:48] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:49] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:50] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:51] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:52] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:53] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:54] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:55] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:56] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:57] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:58] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 15:59] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:00] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:01] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:02] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:03] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:04] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:05] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:06] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:07] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:08] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:09] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:13] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:14] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:15] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
[Mar12 16:16] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:406D.0004: multiplier = 8
```

I've tried to search around the internet for a solution but haven't been able to find anything out.  It is super annoying when I am trying to type and then all of the sudden it stop and then 15 seconds later spits out everything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: I have the same problem using a M560 mouse. The lag is really annoying! What seems to reduce the lag (also seen by the amount of "multiplier = 8" message) is to unplug and plug it again.
Hope, that helps.